# Excel Conditional formating individual cells based on case (upper or lower)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use conditional formatting to highlight individual cells based on the case (upper or lower) of the first character of the cells value.

Example of cell values:

R1  r1

R1 would be highlighted light orange
r1 would be highlighted light green

Range is E3:AZ78

I have found a few posts that deal with this issue but none of the solutions seem to pan out for me.

Thanks in advance for any and all assistance.

Billy

Comment: post what code you have tried so far related to conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the following rule for highlighting cells orange:

```
=AND(E3<>"", EXACT(UPPER(LEFT(E3,1)),LEFT(E3,1)))
```

And by placing a `Not()` around the `EXACT()` statement for the green highlighting.

Hope that does the trick!

Comment: better than mine...I never use Exact so built my own using CODE...you live and learn

Comment: @smackenzie, my general rule: "If it works, you're winning" :) - But glad I could show you a different way!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to check for an upper case character.  This works as a formula in Excel.

It takes the left most character in cell G1, gets the ascii code, and compares it to the ascii code of the same character when converted to upper case.  If it is the same, then it is already in upper case and it produces "Upper", otherwise "Lower".

You could adapt this to work in conditional format by formula.

=IF(CODE(LEFT(G1,1)) = CODE(UPPER(LEFT(G1,1))),"Upper","Lower")

Answer (score 0):

Thank you John your solution worked exceptionally well.

Although instead of using the not for the green highlighting
I Changed the code to say lower instead

AND(E3<>"", EXACT(LOWER(LEFT(E3,1)),LEFT(E3,1)))

again Thank you so very much.

Billy